# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using a form with `PATCH` method and I have a button link(since i already have a submit button and using same form for both store and update) as

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/edit/' . $vehicle -> id) }}">EDIT</a>
```

And my route is

```
Route::patch('/pages/edit/{id}', ['uses' => 'VehicleProcessController@update']);
```

Controller

```
public function update($id)
{
     $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);  

     $input = Input::all();

     $vehicle->update($input);

     return  $input;
}
```

When i click to link `$input` returns null and i am getting

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I am trying to get familiar with L5, how can i fix this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a>` link will trigger a `GET` request, not a `PATCH` request. You can use JS to have it trigger a `PATCH` request, or use a `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` to issue one.

Comment: As i mentioned above i already have a submit button so in this form for store. I am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: Use AJAX to issue a PATCH request, then.